Qt6: Disable drawing of default background for QTreeView items
Prior to Qt 6.5 background for items was rendered only when alternating background for items was specified, allowing QStyledItemDelegate to render background independently. This however was changed by the qt/qtbase@16e0e7c commit.
EDIT: I've found another commit that is part of this regression: qt/qtbase@483ae6c. This one translates PanelItemViewRows into PanelItemViewItems to "properly" render background because it is non-styleable from qss. I don't know why it is done like that instead of introducing something like ::row into qss.
One solution would be to override PE_PanelItemViewRow using QProxyStyle but this does not work with stylesheets which is hard requirement as the app allows custom styling.
Another possibility would be to set ::item in qss to have no background and somehow render it in QStyledItemDelegate but I don't know how to do it in a way that it would be possible to control it using qss.
Incorrect behavior:

Expected one:


Maybe try to change the palette colors or backgroundBrush of the style option in initStyleOption() of the delegate?

Changing it does not impact rendering of the backgrounds in any way. I feel that initStyleOption is called after backgrounds are rendered.

So if you override the paint() of the delegate and do nothing, the panel background is still rendered?

Exactly, this was the first thing that I tried to do.
https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/483ae6c448ff95354c22e7d6e71117a9f9c40421 this commit seems to be the problem as it renders PanelItemViewRow as items and is also used for background of branches which matches the behavior that I see.

Uhm, yeah, I forgot that QTreeView does that in drawRow(). I don't remember if QStyleSheetStyle also prevents overriding styleHint(), but if it doesn't maybe you could try to fix the option.rect there? It's a bit unorthodox (styleHint() is not expected to do that), but if it works...

Resetting option.rect causes content of the item to not be rendered (which is expected), background stays untouched.

No, you don't need to completely reset it, but to resize it. Possibly using the view's visualRect() of the index (but I'm not sure it only refers to the item alone or it also includes the branch decorations).

I managed to find a hacky solution to this problem.
To disable rendering of the background I can abuse this if statement in Qt:
        // For compatibility reasons, QTreeView draws different parts of
        // the background of an item row separately, before calling the
        // delegate to draw the item. The row background of an item is
        // however not separately styleable through a style sheet, but
        // only indirectly through the background of the item. To get the
        // same background for all parts drawn by QTreeView, we have to
        // use the background rule for the item here.
        if (renderRule(w, opt, PseudoElement_ViewItem).hasBackground())
            pseudoElement = PseudoElement_ViewItem;

So disabling background for ::item disables rendering of branches and not-wanted background (I'm using qtsass):
  QTreeView::item {
    &, &:selected, &:hover {
      background: none;
      border: none;
    }
  }

This however denies me from defining background in qss. But as a workarond I create artificial QTreeView widget inside the delegate with some well defined object name, DocumentTreeItems in my case:
TreeWidgetItemDelegate::TreeWidgetItemDelegate(QObject* parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
    artificial = new QTreeView(qobject_cast<QWidget*>(parent));
    artificial->setObjectName("DocumentTreeItems");
    artificial->setFixedSize(0, 0);
}

Thanks to that I can attach styles to this widget inside qss:
  #DocumentTreeItems::item {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: $primaryBackground;

    &:hover {
      border: 1px solid $contrastBorder;
      background-color: $controlWidgetBackground;
    }

    &:selected {
      border: 1px solid $accentBorder;
      background-color: $accentBackground;
    }
  }

Then I can repaint the background using style and referring to my artificial widget in the paint method of delegate:
    style->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter, artificial);

This gives the expected result:

I'm however deeply dissatisfied with this solution, so if anyone knows a better one I'd be glad to hear suggestions.
